# Is there a 64 bit version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

Is there a x64 or ia64 version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2005?  All the information I'm seeing leads me to believe there is only a x86 version.

This link is my evidence that a 64-bit version doesn't exist - http://support.microsoft.com/?id=906892

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope the management studio (and Visual studio for that matter) are still at 32 bit.

Comment: Note that the 32bit version will run on 64bit windows and connect to 64bit sql server just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.

Go to Microsoft website and search for it or try below link.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6053c6f8-82c8-479c-b25b-9aca13141c9e

Answer (score 2):

Please visit the following site.
It worked on my PC.
Windows 7 (64Bit)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796&displaylang=en

Comment: Please consider adding some excerpt for the linked article.